# How to maintain JavaScript breakpoints while developing a Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, debugging

I'm working on a JavaScript function in a Rails 5 application on my localhost, so I open the Chrome debugger tools and add a breakpoint to the application.js file:

[image]

Now I make a change to the JS file and reload the page, and the breakpoint is gone from the Chrome debugger tools:

[image]

Presumably this is because Rails has changed the UID that it appends to the name of the application.js file (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.self-22a4471f17f42....js?body=1) and Chrome can't maintain the breakpoint.

Is there a setting in Rails to avoid this during development?

Comment: Why aren't you using `debugger` in your script?

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that was an option - I've always used breakpoints in the browser's dev tools. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I thought there is a specific reason you're not using it

Comment: Only cos I'd never come across it before - the [Debugging Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) page only talks about using `byebug` for Ruby code

Comment: `byebug` provides ruby equivalent for javacript's `debugger` functionality. I'd like to think the concept was taken from javascript, I could be wrong. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debugger` in your javascript code to create breakpoints.

Example:

```
function youFunction() {
  debugger;
  // do your magic
}
```

Also to address another thing, I think you can set precompilation of assets to false, if that's not an issue for you, in your `config/environments/development.rb` file.

Please take a look at all possible options here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets